# Illustrator: How do I copy a gradient (including direction) from one object to another?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, gradient

I know I can copy a gradient (minus direction) from one object to another, but how do I preserve the direction of the gradient?  (I'm using Illustrator CS6)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Drag the Gradient Filled object to the Graphic Styles Panel.

The angle will be retained in a Graphic Style (along with any other appearance settings)

Then, when you need to reapply the gradient, select the new object and click the Graphic Style in the Panel.

Comment: This solved my issue of not being able to preserve the gradient angle when using the eyedropper tool.